# Finding an ODE with a specific limit cycle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Is there a systematic way to construct an ODE (or a system) with a given periodic function $f(t)$ as an attracting limit cycle?

E.g. starting at $(1,0)$ the limit cycle of $\big\{ \dot{x} = x(1-r)-y, \ \dot{y} = y(1-r)+x \big\}$, or equivalently $\big\{ \dot{r} = r(1-r),\ \dot{\theta} = 1 \big\}$ can be expressed as $x = f(t) = \cos(t)$.

If there is no general way, for which particular kinds of limit cycles (functions) is it easy to find an ODE?

Thanks in advance.